# Como condicionar el WHERE con una variable y una tabla temporal?, query dinamico

Tags: sql-server

Que tal buen día,
tengo una duda con SQL Server, como puedo hacer para que mediante una variable, escoja si quiero agregar el not like o si no lo quiero agregar, tengo este código pero no me funciona, me pone error en la tabla temporal:

```
DECLARE @option CHAR(1)
DECLARE @sql_statement VARCHAR(MAX) = ''
SET @sql_statement = 'SELECT Numero,
                             Revision,
                             Nombre
                      INTO   #REV
                      FROM   dbo.sp_prueba'
IF @option = 'Y'
BEGIN
  SET @sql_statement +=  'WHERE  Revision NOT LIKE ''XL%Dem''
                          AND  Numero > 2'
END
ELSE
 BEGIN
  SET @sql_statement +=  'WHERE  Numero > 2'
 END
EXEC(@sql_statement)
```

Comment: Tengo una duda @cherman5, quieres hacer un insert o un select?

Comment: que tal @JulioMorenoDev, lo que busco es que la consulta se inserte en la tabla temporal, solo que en ocasiones utilizaría la condición de Revision y otras no, por eso es que puse el IF

Comment: No es suficiente decir que te pone error.  Debes compartir el error exacto. No podemos adivinarlo. Pero te diré que parece que el problema es que al concatenar las diferentes porciones de tu SQL, no le estás poniendo un espacio entre la tabla `dbo.sp_prueba` y el `WHERE`. En vista de esto, voto para cerrar la pregunta por ser simplemente un error tipográfico.

Comment: que tal sstan, no es error por el espacio, y como dije, me marca error en la tabla temporal, así sin mas, o bueno me marcaba, acomode el código como me lo indico Julio y funciono

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Aquí te dejo el query dinámico correcto.

```
DECLARE @option CHAR(1)=''
DECLARE @sql_statement VARCHAR(MAX) = ''

SET @sql_statement='insert into #TuTablaTempo 
                  SELECT Numero,
                         Revision,
                         Nombre
                         FROM   dbo.sp_prueba'

IF @option='Y' BEGIN
   SET @sql_statement= @sql_statement + ' WHERE  Revision NOT LIKE ''XL%Dem''
                      AND  Numero > 2'
EXEC(@sql_statement)
END
  ELSE BEGIN
    SET @sql_statement= @sql_statement + ' WHERE  Numero > 2'
    EXEC(@sql_statement)
 END
```

Comment: muchas gracias por la respuesta, intente acomodar el código de esta manera, pero me sigue saliendo el mismo error, Invalid object name '#TablaTempo'

Comment: Y vi cual era el problema, el codigo que me pusiste funciona muy bien, solo que no me queria funcionar porque la tabla temporal aun no se creaba, entonces cambie INSERT INTO #TablaTemporal por solo INTO #TablaTemporal, muchas gracias por tu ayuda!

Comment: Por nada @chernan5, si mi respuesta te funciona me harías gran favor marcarla como respuesta. Gracias!!